# Can't figure how to break field onto individual lines

Tags: html, css

I have a results page that I am trying to adjust. Right now I have 4 fields that I cannot figure out how to control. I have made some progress, but there is something keeping them clustered onto 1 line, I think? My result page is at:

[Results Page](http://integratedresourcemgmt.idxbroker.com/idx/results/listings?pt=sfr&lp=200000&hp=800000&ccz=city&city[]=2150&per=10&srt=prd)

I have 5 items that I think are controlling the field as follows:

```
.IDX-resultsContentMain div {
    color: #333;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.IDX-resultsField-propStatus div{
    margin-left: 100px !important; ;
}
.IDX-resultsField-bedrooms div{
    margin-left: 100px !important; ;
}
.IDX-resultsField-totalBaths div{
    margin-left: 100px !important; ;
}
.IDX-resultsField-partialBaths div{
margin-left: 100px !important; ;
}
```

Something is making these fields group together, maybe it is a php file or something, which is where I don't have much experience.

My goal is to have the fields line up in any sort of logical way. Any ideas? Thanks so much. -Beth

Comment: please share html code

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and update post with sample *inline* in the post.

Answer (score 0):

All of the fields are on the same line cause all divs have `float: left` rule. If you remove it, each div will start with a new line

Comment: I removed the float: left from the only spot that I thought was controlling the field and it worked for the status and bedrooms fields but not the total baths and partial baths field. The fields have a div with margin-left: 100px, so I am not really sure what to do?

Comment: You need to add the following CSS rule:

`.IDX-resultsContentMain .IDX-resultsField-totalBaths,
.IDX-resultsContentMain .IDX-resultsField-partialBaths {
  margin-left: 0;
}`

Comment: That worked perfectly. I only kind of understand it. Is it by adding that code  it gives another command to the fields that were not cooperating?

Comment: The following CSS rule `.IDX-resultsContentMain div {margin-left: 100px;}` is applied to all divs within `.IDX-resultsContentMain`. In some cases, you have nested divs which are still good for that CSS selector. As a result, you got `margin-left: 100px;` applied twice.

Comment: Wonderful Antseburova. Thank You.